# Solution to "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not so much into coding; I just would like to make a simple php application run on my local XAMPP.
Everytime I want to login I get the following two notices:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 47
```

Second one directly below the first:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/login.php

Line Number: 49
```

Having a look at lines 47 to 49 does not help me as I do not get the essence of the error notice:

```
        $this->status = $rsp->data->status;

        if($this->status->OK){
```

It wopuld be greatly appricaited of you could give me a hint what do you. I had a look at fice other "codeigniter Message: Trying to..." questions but I couldn't transfer the answers to my specific case.

All the best
Alex

Comment: $this->status is propably not an object but a string or something else.

Comment: It looks like either $rsp or $rsp->data is not an object. Please add more info on how you obtain $rsp object.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code into your index.php which is located in root directory

if it is development server

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

if it is production server

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); 

if(isset($this->status->OK)&&$this->status->OK)
```